# Reusing a Storyboard Scene but missing NavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I have a 'details' scene that can be navigated to by a drill down search. But I also have a qr reader that when it reads a QR code, should take the user to the same details page. Now, that all works fine. My only issue, is when the I use the scanner, I am not presented with the Navigation Controller to take my self back to the scanner. I am presented with a Back button for the drill down from the table.

What is the best method for giving me a navigation controller that will pop me back to the correct original calling view?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer for those wondering, is WAY similar than I thought. In my example, I simply embedded my Scan scene in a Navigation Controller.

[image]